# Is it possible to have to keys in a custom configsection with the same values?

Tags: c#, app-config, configurationsection

I've the following in my app.config:

```
<XPathFilter>
    <outbound>
     <filter **message="ProductChangeMessage"**  xpath="//acs:productDetails[acs:productType =  'Loan']" />
      <filter **message="ProductChangeMessage"**  xpath="//acs:productDetails[acs:productType = 'Test']" />
   </outbound>
</XPathFilter>
```

I've a set of classes i use to read elements from in here...they work fine except when 2 filters have the same message value. I get

> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: The entry
>   'ProductChangeMessage' has already been added.

Is it not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is No. The error message you got answered your question.